# Cassandra deployment fails on Azure DCOS

Tags: azure, cassandra, dcos

I am trying to deploy cassandra on Azure DC/OS cluster:

```
$ dcos package install cassandra
DC/OS Cassandra Service default configuration requires 3 nodes each with 1.5 CPU shares, 5376MB of memory and 11264MB of disk for running Cassandra Nodes. And, 1 node with 0.5 CPU shares, 2048MB of memory for running the service scheduler.
Continue installing? [yes/no] yes
Installing Marathon app for package [cassandra] version [1.0.21-3.0.10]
Installing CLI subcommand for package [cassandra] version [1.0.21-3.0.10]
New command available: dcos cassandra
DC/OS Apache Cassandra has been successfully installed!
```

but deployment is failing. Could you please see what is wrong?
Here is the log:

```
   I1221 07:16:07.517323 32006 logging.cpp:194] INFO level logging started!
    I1221 07:16:07.517573 32006 fetcher.cpp:498] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"\/tmp\/mesos\/fetch\/slaves\/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2\/root","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"executable":false,"extract":true,"value":"https:\/\/downloads.mesosphere.com\/cassandra\/assets\/1.0.21-3.0.10\/scheduler.zip"}},{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"executable":false,"extract":true,"value":"https:\/\/downloads.mesosphere.com\/cassandra\/assets\/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz"}},{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"executable":false,"extract":true,"value":"http:\/\/downloads.mesosphere.com\/libmesos-bundle\/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz"}}],"sandbox_directory":"\/var\/lib\/mesos\/slave\/slaves\/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2\/frameworks\/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000\/executors\/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001\/runs\/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e","user":"root"}
    I1221 07:16:07.520052 32006 fetcher.cpp:409] Fetching URI 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/1.0.21-3.0.10/scheduler.zip'
    I1221 07:16:07.520078 32006 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
    I1221 07:16:07.520105 32006 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/1.0.21-3.0.10/scheduler.zip'
    I1221 07:16:07.520126 32006 fetcher.cpp:134] Downloading resource from 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/1.0.21-3.0.10/scheduler.zip' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/scheduler.zip'
    I1221 07:16:08.502091 32006 fetcher.cpp:84] Extracting with command: unzip -o -d '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e' '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/scheduler.zip'
    I1221 07:16:09.300681 32006 fetcher.cpp:92] Extracted '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/scheduler.zip' into '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e'
    I1221 07:16:09.300758 32006 fetcher.cpp:547] Fetched 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/1.0.21-3.0.10/scheduler.zip' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/scheduler.zip'
    I1221 07:16:09.300781 32006 fetcher.cpp:409] Fetching URI 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:09.300791 32006 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
    I1221 07:16:09.300819 32006 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:09.300844 32006 fetcher.cpp:134] Downloading resource from 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:10.301225 32006 fetcher.cpp:84] Extracting with command: tar -C '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e' -xf '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:12.163631 32006 fetcher.cpp:92] Extracted '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz' into '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e'
    I1221 07:16:12.163704 32006 fetcher.cpp:547] Fetched 'https://downloads.mesosphere.com/cassandra/assets/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/server-jre-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:12.163719 32006 fetcher.cpp:409] Fetching URI 'http://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:12.163730 32006 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
    I1221 07:16:12.163758 32006 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'http://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:12.163776 32006 fetcher.cpp:134] Downloading resource from 'http://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:12.722585 32006 fetcher.cpp:84] Extracting with command: tar -C '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e' -xf '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:14.569461 32006 fetcher.cpp:92] Extracted '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz' into '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e'
    I1221 07:16:14.569540 32006 fetcher.cpp:547] Fetched 'http://downloads.mesosphere.com/libmesos-bundle/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle-1.8.7-1.0.2.tar.gz'
    I1221 07:16:14.805963 31995 exec.cpp:161] Version: 1.0.1
    I1221 07:16:14.812760 32095 exec.cpp:236] Executor registered on agent e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Failed to load native Mesos library from /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle/lib/libmesos-1.0.1.so
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle/lib/libmesos-1.0.1.so: /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-S2/frameworks/e362a1f3-5829-4e1d-8aa7-ff1bc25e01f8-0000/executors/cassandra.57394975-c74d-11e6-898f-70b3d5800001/runs/764668d3-75a3-4b1c-afe8-1cbeedc2318e/libmesos-bundle/lib/libresolv.so.2: symbol h_errno, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at org.apache.mesos.MesosNativeLibrary.load(MesosNativeLibrary.java:159)
        at org.apache.mesos.MesosNativeLibrary.load(MesosNativeLibrary.java:188)
        at org.apache.mesos.MesosSchedulerDriver.<clinit>(MesosSchedulerDriver.java:61)
        at org.apache.mesos.scheduler.SchedulerDriverFactory.createInternal(SchedulerDriverFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.mesos.scheduler.SchedulerDriverFactory.create(SchedulerDriverFactory.java:90)
        at org.apache.mesos.scheduler.SchedulerDriverFactory.create(SchedulerDriverFactory.java:42)
        at com.mesosphere.dcos.cassandra.scheduler.CassandraScheduler.registerFramework(CassandraScheduler.java:380)
        at com.mesosphere.dcos.cassandra.scheduler.Main.registerJerseyResources(Main.java:71)
        at com.mesosphere.dcos.cassandra.scheduler.Main.run(Main.java:65)
        at com.mesosphere.dcos.cassandra.scheduler.Main.run(Main.java:20)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:40)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:77)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:80)
        at com.mesosphere.dcos.cassandra.scheduler.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Comment: What host machine OS are you using?

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release: 16.04

Comment: @zarinius, can also provide the information on `find | grep libc.so.6` and can do you  `ldd lib/libmesos-1.0.1.so` and `ldd lib/libresolv.so.2` and share the output.